# symfony 3 unrecognized option in services

Tags: php, symfony, service

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my code and why i am getting:

```
Unrecognized option "entity" under "security.providers.our_users"
```

security.yml

```
security:
   providers:
     our_users:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

I was using entity option many times and now im getting this error. I really dont know how to solve this. Any idea?

Does anyone know?

Comment: you should put security related conf in the `app/config/security.yml` che [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) and [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) in the doc

Comment: Yes it is in `app/config/` so i do not know

Comment: Sorry i made a misstake, i edited question

Comment: tab providers in

Comment: Also done and getting still the same

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that ? 
Are you using FOS User Bundle ? You need to write that in config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: i am not using fos bundle

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to clean your cache ? : `php bin/console c:c --no-warmup`

If it's not this, you can do the same thing differently by creating a [custom user provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html)

Comment: I followed knpuniversity guide for this and it should work. I dont want to make custom user provider